# What could be causing 'No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'' error in Angular forms?

Tags: html, angularjs

> "No directive found with exportAs 'ngModel'.ngtsc(-998003)
> edit-employee.component.ts(11, 32): Error occurs in the template of component EditEmployeeComponent."

This is the error message that I am getting.

I tried looking for the answer. The solution that I got was to import the FormsModule in the module.ts file, which I have already done. But, I did not get the answer to that specific error message.

It is only the ngModel that is troubling. I tried changing the spelling(the case of the letters) but nothing happened. I am using angular 16.

This is my edit-employee.component.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="container-xl">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table-title">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <h4><b>Update Employee</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <a href="#" routerlink="/Home" class="btn btn-success back"><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>
                 Back</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form #employeeform="ngForm">
          <div class="table-content">
            <div class="form-group p-10 row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="FirstName" class="p-t-b-10">First Name<span class="requiredStar">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" required maxlength="255"
                  (ngmodel)= "editEmployeeForm.FirstName" name="FirstName" #firstname="ngModel">
                <div *ngif= "FirstName.errors && isSubmitted" class="alert alert-danger validationError">
                  <div hidden="!FirstName.errors?.['required']">
                    First Name is required
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group p-10 row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="LastName" class="p-t-b-10">Last Name<span class="requiredStar">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LastName" required maxlength="255"
                  (ngmodel)= "editEmployeeForm.LastName" name="LastName" #lastname="ngModel">
                <div *ngif= "LastName.errors && isSubmitted" class="alert alert-danger validationError">
                  <div hidden= "!LastName.errors?.['required']">
                    Last Name is required
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group p-10 row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="p-t-b-10">Email<span class="requiredStar">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" required maxlength="255"
                  (ngmodel)= "editEmployeeForm.Email" name="Email" #email="ngModel"
                  pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}$" readonly>
                <div *ngif= "Email.errors && isSubmitted" class="alert alert-danger validationError">
                  <div hidden= "!Email.errors?.['required']">
                    Email is required
                  </div>
                  <div hidden= "!Email.errors?.['touched'] && !Email.errors?.['pattern']">
                    Email is invalid
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group p-10 row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="p-t-b-10">Address<span class="requiredStar">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="Address" required (ngmodel)= "editEmployeeForm.Address" name="Address"
                  #address= "ngModel"></textarea>
                <div *ngif= "Address.errors && isSubmitted" class="alert alert-danger validationError">
                  <div hidden= "!Address.errors?.['required']">
                    Address is required
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group p-10 row">
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="p-t-b-10">Phone<span class="requiredStar">*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Phone" required maxlength="10"
                  (ngmodel)= "editEmployeeForm.Phone" name="Phone" #phone="ngmModel" pattern="^\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}$">
                <div *ngif= "Phone.errors && isSubmitted" class="alert alert-danger validationError">
                  <div [hidden]= "Phone.errors?.['required']">
                    Phone is required
                  </div>
                  <div hidden= "!Phone.errors?.['touched'] && !Phone.errors?.['pattern']">
                    Phone is invalid
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="EditEmployee(employeeForm.form.valid)">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my edit.component.ts code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { HttpProviderService } from '../Service/http-provider.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-employee',
  templateUrl: './edit-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-employee.component.scss']
})
export class EditEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  editEmployeeForm: employeeForm = new employeeForm();

  @ViewChild("employeeForm")
  employeeForm!: NgForm;

  isSubmitted: boolean = false;
  employeeId: any;
  Phone: any;

  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
    private httpProvider: HttpProviderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employeeId = this.route.snapshot.params['employeeId'];
    this.getEmployeeDetailById();
  }
  getEmployeeDetailById() {
    this.httpProvider.getEmployeeDetailById(this.employeeId).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data = null && data.body != null) {
        var resultData = data.body;
        if (resultData) {
          this.editEmployeeForm.Id = resultData.id;
          this.editEmployeeForm.FirstName = resultData.firstName;
          this.editEmployeeForm.LastName = resultData.lastName;
          this.editEmployeeForm.Email = resultData.email;
          this.editEmployeeForm.Address = resultData.address;
          this.editEmployeeForm.Phone = resultData.phone;
        }
      }
    },
      (_error: any) => { });
  }

  EditEmployee(isValid: any) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (isValid) {
      this.httpProvider.saveEmployee(this.editEmployeeForm).subscribe(async data => {
        if (data = null && data.body != null) {
          var resultData = data.body;
          if (resultData = null && resultData.isSuccess) {
            if (resultData = null && resultData.isSuccess) {
              this.toastr.success(resultData.message);
              setTimeout(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
              }, 500);
            }
          }
        }
      },
        async error => {
          this.toastr.error(error.message);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/Home']);
          }, 500);
        });
    }
  }
}

export class employeeForm {
  Id: number = 0;
  FirstName: string = "";
  LastName: string = "";
  Email: string = "";
  Address: string = "";
  Phone: string = "";
}
```

This is my app.module.ts code.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent, } from './home/home.component';
import { AddEmployeeComponent } from './add-employee/add-employee.component';
import { EditEmployeeComponent } from './edit-employee/edit-employee.component';
import { ViewEmployeeComponent } from './view-employee/view-employee.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AddEmployeeComponent,
    EditEmployeeComponent,
    ViewEmployeeComponent],
  imports: [
    
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: it's : **[ngModel]** (see the upper-case and the interpolation  `[` `]`) to one-way binding and **[(ngModel)]** to two-way-binding (when change the input change also the variable) and ***ngIf**. check also your 'hidden="!Phone.errors?.."` (you also need use interpolation: `[` `]`). You have also a `#phone="ngmModel"` BTW you should use a service to get the data instead of use the httpClient in your component

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you so much for your help. This solved my problem. But it is asking me to write the Model in lower case.